# Firefox addon fires twice on YouTube

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have created a single js on the add-on builder containing the following code:

```
require("tabs").on("ready", logURL);

function logURL(tab) {
    console.log("HELLO");
 // runScript(tab);
}
```

What I see in the Error Console (on the messages panel) is the message "HELLO" and then the message goes away. On any other tab the message remains. It seems like the page is redirecting or reloads.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you share a link to your builder project? It would make this easier to debug.

Comment: @canuckistani [here it is](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/156942/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

The Error Console doesn't get cleared when the page reloads. The issue is rather that the Error Console can hold only a limited number of messages and YouTube produces lots of warnings, your message simply gets pushed away. Note that the messages panel is simply a filter, switching to it doesn't help you avoid the overall limit.

You should send a more informative message to the console, e.g.:

```
console.log("Hello from " + tab.url);
```

My bet is that the first message isn't even associated with YouTube - it is either `about:blank` or `about:newtab` (the document that gets loaded into a new tab originally, before YouTube starts loading). I tried your add-on and it definitely sends only one message for YouTube, the message before it refers to the blank tab.

Comment: Thank you. The only problem then is that any log messages disappears immediately prior to be able to see them.Is there any way to log at the firebug's console?